# java filter using jTextfieldKeyReleased

Tags: java

hello everyone please I need your help.
I want to add a filter to my table. Here is a part of the code. Actually,  after adding rows on my table and I try to search using the filter when I tape a key the rows disappear. How can I make this filter work ?
Thank you

```
private void filter1(String query)       
{
DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) addtab.getModel();
TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> filter1=new TableRowSorter<>(model);
addtab.setRowSorter(filter1);
filter1.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(query));
}
private void searchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    String query=search.getText().toLowerCase();
filter1(query);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner post a [mcve]. `"that you can see in the image"`, what image?

Comment: Did you register a KeyEventListener on the seach field?

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer No. please would you tell me how to fix it? I'm a  
beginner in java ...

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example.

Basically the examples uses a `DocumentListener` to listen for changes in the text field and then applies the filter.

Answer (score -1):

Swing has a wonderful tutorial written by the Java documentation team.
It is quite extensive and explains how to implement a KeyListener here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

In your case, in your initialization code, add something like

```
search.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { 
    @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 
       // check if e is actually a character, read up about focus handling
       searchKeyReleased(e);
    }
});
```

(haven't compiled this, but you get the idea)

Comment: (1-) Don't use a KeyListener, Swing has newer and better API's. In this case it would be a `DocumentListener` to listen for changes in the text field. Your suggested code won't work for example is backspace is used, or text is pasted into the text field.

Comment: true, forgot about DocumentListener. Will also change to keyPressed again. Needs more filtering then

Comment: btw, disagree on the statement of 'better' API ;) It has additional API compared to AWT. You'll still be subjected to AWT classes if you learn about Swing programming